# How to replace the 'this.' in the functional React Native with Hooks?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, echarts

I'm trying to use the following [react-native-echarts-wrapper](https://github.com/tomLadder/react-native-echarts-wrapper#dynamic-loading-example) but in my projects all my components are made using hooks. So, when I have a state variable that changes its state I want to execute the function `setOption(option)` where the option contains the state value.

The problem is that in the documentation the function `setOption()` is referenced using `this.chart.setOption(option)`. If I try to put without the `this.` I get a message where `chart` is undefined and if I only use function I get the message saying that `setOption is not a function`.

So is there a way to get the reference of the chart component and its functions using RN Hooks?

Here is my code:

```
const [radarChartData, setRadarChartData] = React.useState([])
const option = { 
title: {
    show:false,
    text: 'Gráfico Radar'
},
tooltip: {},
legend: {
orient: 'horizontal',
position:'bottom',
left: 0,
bottom:0,
type:'scroll',             
pageButtonPosition:'end', 
data: chartColumnNameArray,
},
radar: {
    radius:'70%',
    name: {
        textStyle: {
            color: '#fff',
            backgroundColor: '#999',
            borderRadius: 3,
            padding: [3, 5]
        }
    },
    indicator: chartValueArray.map((item, index)=>{
    return {name:chartColumnNameArray[index].toUpperCase().substring(0,5).concat('.'), max:maxValue}
    })
},
series: [{
    name: 'TEST',
    type: 'radar',          
    data: radarChartData <------------------- //when this state changes I would setOptions and reload chart
}]
};

<View style={{display:  visibleChart==="radarchart"?"flex":"none", width:'100%', height:'60%'}} >                     
         <ECharts option={option} additionalCode={React.useEffect(()=>{this.chart.setOption(option)},[radarChartData])}/>                                                              
</View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the 'useRef' hook to get access to the chart, even in the examples that are provided they use a reference to the chart and update it.
I've made a basic example to change the background color which will give you the idea on how use the hook with the charts. Simply set the ref and use chart.current instead of this.chart.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { ECharts } from 'react-native-echarts-wrapper';

export default function App() {
  const chart = React.useRef(null);
  const option = {
    xAxis: {
      type: 'category',
      data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
    },
    yAxis: {
      type: 'value',
    },
    series: [
      {
        data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
        type: 'line',
      },
    ],
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.chartContainer}>
      <Button
        title="Update"
        onPress={() => {
          if (chart) {
            chart.current.setBackgroundColor('rgba(0,255,0,0.3)');
          }
        }}
      />
      <ECharts
        ref={chart}
        option={option}
        backgroundColor="rgba(93, 169, 81, 0.4)"
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  chartContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Comment: hi @kd12345 you will have to check on https://reactnavigation.org/docs/state-persistence

Comment: I already have something similar implemented where when a user already has an account instead of navigating to welcome screen, user navigates to password screen. My problem is eg. say im on the profile screen in the app then i navigate to whatsapp then back to the app, when i go back to the app in on the home screen instead of the profile screen.

Comment: You maybe having a async storage to have the login state but the navigation state is different and you might have to check the link I gave you

Comment: Thank you will have a dive into it and update you